# Disable checkout when certain product isn't in cart above certain cart total

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to know if it's possible to disable checkout when there isn't a certain product in the cart above a certain cart total in WooCommerce.

I found a code which does the exact opposite I think:

```
function sv_wc_prevent_checkout_for_category() {
    
    // set the slug of the category for which we disallow checkout
    $category = 'clothing';
    
    // get the product category
    $product_cat = get_term_by( 'slug', $category, 'product_cat' );
    
    // sanity check to prevent fatals if the term doesn't exist
    if ( is_wp_error( $product_cat ) ) {
        return;
    }
    
    $category_name = '<a href="' . get_term_link( $category, 'product_cat' ) . '">' . $product_cat->name . '</a>';
    
    // check if this category is the only thing in the cart
    if ( sv_wc_is_category_alone_in_cart( $category ) ) {
        
        // render a notice to explain why checkout is blocked
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'Hi there! Looks like your cart only contains products from the %1$s category &ndash; you must purchase a product from another category to check out.', $category_name ), 'error' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'sv_wc_prevent_checkout_for_category' );


/**
 * Checks if a cart contains exclusively products in a given category
 * 
 * @param string $category the slug of the product category
 * @return bool - true if the cart only contains the given category
 */
function sv_wc_is_category_alone_in_cart( $category ) {
        
    // check each cart item for our category
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        
        // if a product is not in our category, bail out since we know the category is not alone
        if ( ! has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $cart_item['data']->id ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
        
    // if we're here, all items in the cart are in our category
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes it's possible to disable checkout when there isn't a certain product in the cart above a certain cart total in WooCommerce… But we expect you to provide your real code attempt in your question. Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I'm sorry, I forgot adding it. It's now there.

Comment: *I found a code which does the exact opposite **I think***, you should inspect the code and understand what it does first. People here won't be looking at that code and try to understand what it does instead of you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, we need to see what you've tried in order to help you.
You stated,

> ...possible to disable checkout when there isn't a certain product in
> the cart above a certain cart total in WooCommerce.

So you're looking at the cart_items array, for a specific item and its count in the cart session:

```
foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item) {
    echo $item['product_id'];
    echo $item['quantity'];
}
```

Now follow what you have above, and you should be able to make a function that prevents checkout if a certain item with a certain count don't exist in the cart.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately I'm very bad at coding, but I'm trying my best. I understand your first code for looking at the cart_items array, but how can I combine this with my sent code?

Comment: I would suggest looking for someone to handle this for you. There are several outsourcing services for code help, such as freelancer.com